# Method not called on object in ViewController ( = ViewScoped ManagedBean)

Tags: jsf, managed-bean

Simple enough question... inside a commandLink's action attribute, can I call a method on an object provided by a viewController? I can't get the following setup to work, and I don't know what the problem is - I don't get errors, there's just nothing happening.

#### TestObject

```
public class TestObject {
    public void testMethod() {
        System.out.println("This is a test method");
    }
}
```

#### ViewController

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ViewController {

    private TestObject testObject = new TestObject();

    public TestObject getTestObject() {
        return testObject;
    }

    public void testMethod() {
        testObject.testMethod();
    }
}
```

#### JSF

```
<!-- This does not work -->
<h:commandLink action="#{viewController.testObject.testMethod}" value="On internal Object"/>
<!-- This works -->
<h:commandLink action="#{viewController.testMethod}" value="On ViewController"/>
```

---

EDIT: Sorry, forgot to mention it: I tried to call `testMethod()` and also `viewController.getTestObject().testMethod()` to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, that the `action` parameter expects a method, not a object property.
Try to call:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{viewController.testObject.testMethod()}" value="On internal Object"/>
```

Then the property `testObject` from the `viewController` gets received and `testMethod()` get invoked.

Comment: `TestObject#testMethod` is a method, not a bean property

Comment: True. I can't interpret your comment, what do you mean? Did i state otherwise?

Comment: `TestObject#testMethod` means method `testMethod` on class `TestObject`. How can you prove that `action="#{viewController.testObject.testMethod}"` invokes `viewController#testObject()#testMethod()` (thus failing) instead of `viewController#getTestObject()#testMethod()`?

Comment: You can step through the evaluation progress if you want to. I'm rephrasing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{viewController.testObject.testMethod()}" value="On internal Object"/>
```